# How can i get a gap from a history table for repeating groups over time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a historical table with data like as bellow :

```
SK ID STATUS EFF_DT EXP_DT 
1 486007909 APP 7/22/2009  8/22/2009
2 486007909 APP 8/22/2009  10/01/2009
3 486007909 CAN 10/01/2009 11/01/2009
4 486007909 CAN 11/02/2009 12/12/2009
5 486007909 APP 12/12/2009 NULL
```

The `EXP_DT is null` mean that the row is active.

I want to return a group of data each time `Status` changes

The expected result like as bellow :

```
SK ID STATUS EFF_DT EXP_DT                 GAP
1 486007909 APP 7/22/2009  8/22/2009        1
2 486007909 APP 8/22/2009  10/01/2009       1
3 486007909 CAN 10/01/2009 11/01/2009       2
4 486007909 CAN 11/02/2009 12/12/2009       2
5 486007909 APP 12/12/2009 NULL             3
```

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is classic gaps-and-islands problem.**

We can solve it by using `LAG` to check for differences, then a windowed `COUNT` to get the `GAP` number.

You may want to add a partitioning clause, such as `PARTITION BY ID`

```sql
SELECT *,
  GAP = COUNT(IsDiff) OVER (ORDER BY EFF_DT ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      IsDiff = CASE WHEN LAG(STATUS, 1, '') OVER (ORDER BY EFF_DT) <> STATUS THEN 1 END
    FROM YourTable t
) t
```